# Excel Cell Formatting with C# changed

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, cell

I have a C# program. One method of it is to create an excel sheet, fill it with data, format the data and save as xls file. For formatting I used code like

```
oSheet.get_Range("F1", "P1").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#.##0,00 €";
oSheet.get_Range("F50", "F50").Formula = "=summe(F1:F49)";
```

and it worked without problems.

Recently I did some other program changes (got nothing to do with this certain method) and build a new exe. Now the cell formattings are not working. I had to change the code to

```
oSheet.get_Range("F1", "P1").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $";
oSheet.get_Range("F50", "F50").Formula = "=sum(F1:F49)";
```

to get the formatting to work again. Even if I undo all the changes and rebuild the exe, formatting is still not working. Can someone please explain why the old code is not working anymore if I rebuild the exe?

I am using,

- Visual Studio 2010
- .Net Framework 4
- Office 2003

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the culture seems to have been changed from German to US, check this and modify to change it to German.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: That was also my thought. But where can it be changed? I am not setting the culture anywhere in the code and system culture is always German.